# How to override the log path for command line jobs invoked using "rails runner"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My Rails3 application includes several "rails runner" jobs invoked via cron.

I would like to send the output from jobs run via cron to a **different** log file then the log output from normal web requests.

I'd like to avoid creating a separate environment just to do this because everything is identical except for the location of the log output.

The best suggestion I could cobble together from similar questions was to reset the paths.log config after initialization, by doing something like the following...

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.some_job
        Rails.configuration.paths.log = "/path/to/cron.log"
        //do some stuff
    end
end
```

... but unfortunately that doesn't work.  The log output still appears in log/{environment}.log.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new('/path/to/cron.log')

    def self.some_job
        //do some stuff
    end
end
```